# How can I eliminate the first x number of elements from each part of a character vector in R?

Tags: r

I have the following character vector of length 3:

```
test <- c("old_information", "old_car", "old_sting")

typeof(test) --> [1] "character"
length(test) --> [1] 3
```

I want to iterate through each element of `test` so it ultimately turns into the equivalent of:

```
test <- c("information", "car", "sting")
```

In other words: I would want to maintain the length of the character array but eliminate the same number of elements from each component (the 4 characters that spell 'old_' in front of each element.)

How could I do this?

Comment: `test <- sub('old_', '', test)`

Comment: Beautiful! Simple and elegant. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you might actually want some regex replacement logic here:

```r
test <- c("old_information", "old_car", "old_sting")
output <- sub("^.*?_", "", test)
output

[1] "information" "car"         "sting"
```

This would strip off all content from the start of each string up to, and including, the first underscore.  If your logic really be to just strip off the first 5 characters, then just use `substr`:

```r
output <- substr(test, 5, nchar(test))
```